# Using client side search in react

Tags: reactjs, search, setstate

Search function is working perfectly fine in the console log but when I try to assign that value to rows which is a state. So I setState the rows inside the setState in searchHandler. I know I'm making a mistake but I don't know how to rectify it. OMIT THE UNDECLARED STATES, MINIFIED THE CODE TO WHAT'S NEEDED

```
function searchingFor(searchingTerm) {
        return function(x){
            // console.log("searching",x);
            return x.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchingTerm.toLowerCase())|| false;
        }
    }

    class Main extends React.Component{

        componentWillMount(){
            this.props.fetchTopicsTableContent(this.state.sortBy,'ASC',0,this.props.match.params.CategoryName).then(result=> (this.setState({rows:result.payload.data})))
            this.props.countTableContent(this.props.match.params.CategoryName).then(result=>(this.setState({count:result.payload})));
        }

        constructor(props){
            super(props);

            this.state={
                rows:"",
                searchTerm:"",
                items:""
            }
        }

        onSubmit(values){
            values.preventDefault();

        }

        onSearchHandler(e){
            this.setState({searchTerm:e.target.value},()=>{
                {this.state.rows.filter(searchingFor(this.state.searchTerm)).map(item=>{
                    console.log(item);
                     //this.setState({rows:item})
                })}
            })
        }

        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    <h3>Topics</h3>
                    <hr/>
                    <div>
                        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
                            <input type="text"
                                   className="searchBar"
                                   value={this.state.searchTerm}
                                   onChange={this.onSearchHandler.bind(this)}
                            />
                        </form>
                   </div>
               </div>
             )
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay so lets start with binding your functions in the constructor, not in the markup, clean things up :P

Next, i'm not sure you understand how setting state works as your function goes against it's basic use. You are correctly setting the first state and using the callback (Because it takes time for state to actually be set) which is great. The callback function it's where it goes downhill.

Your mapping function is loading up several setState calls instantly, for each one console.log() will run successfully, but only one of the setStates will actually take effect. On top of that, even if it did work, your `rows` state will only have a single item. Lets try this:

```
onSearchHandler(e){
    this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
            rows: prevState.rows.filter(searchingFor(e.target.value)),
            searchTerm: e.target.value,
        }
    });
}
```

That will get you what I assume is the desired result... you should only ever do one setState at a time, unless you are waiting for the callback on each one, because you can't be sure each one will complete before the next.

Comment: Well work through it :P Without knowing what those values are, my code could be slightly off, i'm just offering the better structure :D

EDIT: I just missed a bracket haha

Comment: Yaa found out the bracket is missing.. but not working correctly even now it is showing errors

Comment: Yeah like I said, take some time and work through why it is showing errors :) it's a learning experience, i'm sure it is just something minor, but the method i've provided is definitely the preferred structure

Comment: Ok thanks for the lesson. I will try to rectify it. If not I'll ask you after trying out.

Comment: I tried and failed, managed to get the results using persist(),but when I backspace the input it doesn't show the previous output, please need help

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is fine, but the  code looks clumsy.I refactored the code so that only necessary logic is present and instead of `bind` use arrow functions.
Here, try this code on [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rows: ["asd", "bsd", "csd", "dsd", "esd"],
      items: []
    }
  }

  onSearchHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({ items: this.state.rows.filter(str => str.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase()))})
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Topics</h3>
        <input type="text"
               className="searchBar" 
               onChange={(e) => this.onSearchHandler(e)}/>
        <p>{this.state.items.join('\n')}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: I want to set the state of the rows

Comment: You want to store the search results in the `rows`.is that it? @GowthamKoushik

Comment: yeah.. but when you store it and when you backspace in the results it doesn't show you the output

Comment: It shouldn't happen when you call it as an `onChange` callback.
Did you run this code on codeSandbox?

Comment: It says str.toLowerCase is not a function